# Did god create logic?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, ontology, theology

If God made logic, the process itself requires pre-existing logic. Since logic must be eternal, it's doubtful God created it. Did God create logic, or is it always there?

Comment: God created the universe but logic is humN. It was created by Pamenides, Plato and Aristotle.

Comment: My logic is: no, God does not created logic. Logic is a way to predict behavior of practical experiment. If 1, 2, 3 expressing some truth, then 1+1 = 2 meet some circumstances to be true, but same truth, 1+1 = 3 degenerate in falsity, because do not meet some circumstances. Therefore, even if we have some truth, truth can degenerate in falsity, because does not meet desired [circumstances.](https://medium.com/@gvitalie/zero-is-odd-or-even-number-9472f489bf94) Therefore, logic is relative, even if truth may be absolute, and truth can degenerate in falsity, because logic is relative.

Comment: @I vote to close the question. - Please define first your concept of God. Then 2) pose a question concerning the arguments in favour and against God. If you are convinced that God exists, then 3) pose a question for arguments that God has created logic, and make clear which logic you mean.

Comment: See e.g.  Andrew Pessin, [Divine Simplicity and the Eternal Truths Descartes and the Scholastics (Philosophia, vol. 38, issue 1, 2010)](https://www.academia.edu/104277073/Divine_Simplicity_and_the_Eternal_Truths_Descartes_and_the_Scholastics?uc-sb-sw=57218097) for a discussion of the well-known "Descartes' view that God freely created the eternal truths, such that He could have done otherwise than He did."

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to define what is God ?Even if we don’t define God and  we ask about the origin of logic then rudimentary logic can be understood as an innate ability to satisfy desires. Consider the logic - if you are hungry then you must search for food , or , if you are thirsty then you must search for something to drink.
Cravings are more fundamental than any apparent understanding of logic. You don’t need to understand logic , when you are thirsty or hungry. The logic automatically gets executed. Moreover, we are not purely logical beings. We sometimes go mad. We indulge in irrational behaviour. Did God created madness or irrationality? No. He didn’t. Did God created cravings to eat and drink ? No. He didn’t because it ultimately leads to suffering.

Therefore we can safely say that logic arises , changes and vanishes. But who created the logic does not apply because there is an absence of true mind or at least a mind which is superior than cravings.

Comment: God did not create suffering? That's too facile a solution. In the Christian world [theodicy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodicy) is generally accepted as a fundamental (Christian) question. There are analogous issues/paradoxes across [all religions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/64065/37256)

Comment: @Rushi Even the God suffers. Why would God create his own and his followers suffering?

Answer (score 0):

> *You say you don't believe in God, yet you believe in grammar*
> Nietzsche

Logic and grammar are quite similar for the purposes of this question.
And they both point to the paradoxes that arise in the belief in a literal Creator-God.

Also related are the set theory paradoxed of Cantor and Russell which arise due to *unrestricted quantification*.
Which in turn is related to unrestricted "Creator-ability".

Also related is the quip that used to be directed against the Windows OS: *Why does Windows have a shutdown in its startup menu but no startup?*
Hint: The frame for the menu — a running OS — does not exist at startup.

All the above are framing issues. What happens without a frame?

Answer (score 0):

Logic is the (formal) rational representation of the laws of the universe. Logic is moreover created by men, while the laws of the universe are not created by men.